# jest mock file's variables and change function behaviour

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write test case for my router. I have const object which I want to mock during test case. How can I change the user object within the test file.

```
const user = {
  isAuthenticated: true
};

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        user.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

test.js

```
it("should return login route", () => {
    const route = <PrivateRoute path="/" component={()=>{}} />
    expect(route)..toMatchSnapshot();
});

it("should return home route", () => {
    const route = <PrivateRoute path="/" component={()=>{}} />
    expect(route)..toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: If you don't export `user`, you can't. It's unclear why it has to be a constant that is unreachable from anywhere else.

Comment: @estus: `const user ` is meant to consume by only this file that's why I have put it inside this file itself. even if I export user how can I make that the test case use the exported one?

Comment: Is user changed inside this module too? Using constants to store global state isn't a good practice, particularly because this makes testing more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

`user` should be available outside the module for testability purposes:

```
export const user = {
  isAuthenticated: true
};
```

This way it can be mocked in tests

```
user.isAuthenticated = false;
```

Original value should be preserved in order to not cross-contaminate tests:

```
let originalIsAuthenticated;

beforeEach(() => {
  originalIsAuthenticated = user.isAuthenticated;
});

afterEach(() => {
  user.isAuthenticated = originalIsAuthenticated;
});
```